# Why am i able to use a input variable declared inside a nested while loop outside of it?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm currently trying to practice python by creating a somple Rock Paper Scissor game. The game works but, I'm confused as to why im able to use the variable "tF" out side of the while loop(the print statement at the end works), because i was under the impression that a variable declared inside a loop is only available inside it.

```py
while True:
    print("rock = R paper = P scissor = S")
    p1 = input("player1 please input: ")
    p2 = input("player2 please input: ")
    rPS(p1, p2)
       while True:
        print("Would you like to play again:")
        tF = input("Enter Yes or No: ")
        if tF == "Yes" or tF == "No":
            break
        else:
            print("That is an invalid input please enter again")
    if tF == "Yes":
        continue
    elif tF == "No":
        break

print(tF)
```

Comment: because `while` loop do not create new scope for variables. Same as another statements like: `if`, `for`, etc.

Comment: thank you. I understand now